# IsNull function in DB2 SQL?

Tags: sql, null, db2

Is there a performant equivalent to the isnull function for DB2?

Imagine some of our products are internal, so they don't have names:

```
Select product.id, isnull(product.name, "Internal) 
From product
```

Might return:

```
1 Socks 
2 Shoes 
3 Internal 
4 Pants
```

Answer (score 42):

For what its worth, COALESCE is similiar but

```
IFNULL(expr1, default)
```

is the exact match you're looking for in DB2.

COALESCE allows multiple arguments, returning the first NON NULL expression, whereas IFNULL only permits the expression and the default.

Thus

```
SELECT product.ID, IFNULL(product.Name, "Internal") AS ProductName
FROM Product
```

Gives you what you're looking for as well as the previous answers, just adding for completeness.

Comment: +1 for giving an *exact* match for the IsNull statement.  I voted up the accepted answer as well, but I'm using yours instead. THANKS!

Answer (score 5):

In DB2 there is a function NVL(field, value if null).

Example:

SELECT ID, NVL(NAME, "Internal) AS NAME, NVL(PRICE,0) AS PRICE FROM PRODUCT WITH UR;

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with DB2, but have you tried COALESCE?

ie:

```
SELECT Product.ID, COALESCE(product.Name, "Internal") AS ProductName
FROM Product
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Select Product.ID, VALUE(product.Name, "Internal") AS ProductName from Product
```

Comment: Er, yes.  However, note that `VALUE(...)` [is a synonym for `COALESCE(...)`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0000868.htm); the optimizer is probably swapping out the call for you.  Personally, I recommend avoiding non-ANSI semantics where possible (that is, use `COALESCE(...)` instead).

Answer (score 0):

`COALESCE` function same  `ISNULL` function
Note. you must use `COALESCE` function with same data type of column that you check is null.

Answer (score 0):

I think `COALESCE` function partially similar to the `isnull`, but try it.

Why don't you go for null handling functions through application programs, it is better alternative.

Comment: COALESCE is different in that you can feed it a variable number of parameters and it will return the first non-null, with an optional default. So if I have varA, varB and VarC any of which might be null (say they come from different tables in an outer join) and if all are null I want an empty string, I could use COALESCE(varA,varB,varC,'') and get the first of them that wasn't null, or an empty string if they are all null. IFNULL (ISNULL in T-SQL) is an all or nothing.

Answer (score 0):

hope this might help someone else out there

```
  SELECT 
.... FROM XXX XX
WHERE
....
AND(
       param1 IS NULL
       OR XX.param1 = param1
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option, in case you need to use if/else, is:

```
NVL2 (string_to_be_tested, string_if_not_null, string_if_null);
```

i.e.:

```
SELECT product.ID, NVL2(product.Name, "Internal", "External") AS ProductName
FROM Product;
```