# SQL Command ISNULL for ODBC Connection

Tags: sql, odbc, openedge

I'm connected to an OpenEdge DataServer via ODBC (not our product, we are just accessing their database, I hardly have any information and certainly no help from the other side).

Anyhow, I just need to execute a simple Select, add a couple of rows and I need the equivalent of an IsNull statement.

Basically I'd like to execute

```
SELECT ISNULL(NULL,'test')
```

This fails with a Syntax Error. I've looked around at something they misleadingly call a "documentation" but there are only references to SP_SQL_ISNULL but I can't get that to work either. I'm fit in T-SQL, so any pointers in any direction appreciated, even if it's just a RTFM with a link to TFM :)

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Catalin and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65071/isnull-function-in-db2-sql) I got on the right track. I kept thinking I needed a OpenEdge specific function but actually I needed to use only ODBC SQL syntax.

To get what

```
ISNULL(col,4)
```

does you can use

```
COALESCE(col,4)
```

which "returns the data type of expression with the highest data type precedence. If all expressions are nonnullable, the result is typed as nonnullable."[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)

Basically it will convert to 4 if the value is null (and therefore not convertable).

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100% sure, but I think ODBC driver expects a valid SQL statement, and not an DBMS specific SQL statement, like the one you provided.

Comment: Could you explain further? Do you mean I should be running the select on a table. I am actually just doing SELECT ISNULL(CountMe,0) + ISNULL(CountMe2,0) FROM Table

Thanks