# SQL Select statement returning NULL

Tags: sql, null, db2-400

I have the following CASE statement in my SELECT clause:

```
       CASE HHHCRIN
       WHEN 'Y' THEN HHHINVN ELSE 'N/A'
       END AS "Credit Memo Document Number",
```

Can someone tell me why I get a NULL rather than N/A?

Comment: is HHHINVN null?  What i the value of HHHCRIN?

Comment: HHHCRIN is 'Y' or 'N', HHHINVN is defined as S 7,0 it is an invoice number.

Comment: Ok, what i'm getting at is, a) could HHHCRIN be null? or b) could HHHCRIN = Y, but HHHINVN is null, so your case would be working?

Comment: HHHINVN always has a value, if HHHCRIN is 'Y' I want to show a blank rather than the invoice number.

Comment: Well you have the case the wrong way round then `when 'y' then '' else HHINVN`

Comment: To clarify, I tried a blank at first and when that didn't work I tried setting the value to N/A.

Comment: Yes, but either way it returns a NULL rather than a blank.

Comment: look at https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_isnull.asp

Comment: I am using OS400 DB2, I do not have an ISNULL function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65071/isnull-function-in-db2-sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the comments

> HHHCRIN is 'Y' or 'N', HHHINVN is defined as S 7,0 it is an invoice
> number.

You can't return a string, be it blanks or 'N/A' when the return column is numeric.

Since Db2 can't implicitly convert 'N/A' to a number, you get null.

Try returning all strings...

```
   CASE HHHCRIN
   WHEN 'Y' THEN char(HHHINVN) ELSE 'N/A'
   END AS "Credit Memo Document Number",
```

Comment: Thank you Charles! That worked, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Sorry Charles, I am relatively new to this, what is an up vote and how would I do that?

Comment: @DanB. click the up arrow next to the answer.   Have you taken the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)?

Comment: I did that but I get a message about not having enough reputation to cast a vote.